# PyTest Tornado: 'SimpleAsyncHTTPClient' is not iterable

Tags: python, tornado, pytest

Trying to make test code for long polling under PyTest, Tornado.

My test code is at below.

**conftest.py**

```
from tornado.httpclient import  AsyncHTTPClient


@pytest.fixture
async def tornado_server():
    print("\ntornado_server()")

@pytest.fixture
async def http_client(tornado_server):
    client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    return client


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session')
def event_loop(request):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()
```

test_my.py

```
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPRequest, HTTPError
def test_http_client(event_loop):
    url = 'http://httpbin.org/get'
    resp = event_loop.run_until_complete(http_client(url))
    assert b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' in resp
```

I expected this result finish as success.
But it failed.

> ```
> def test_http_client(event_loop):
>     url = 'http://httpbin.org/get'
>     resp = event_loop.run_until_complete(http_client(url))
>    assert b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' in resp E       TypeError: argument of type 'SimpleAsyncHTTPClient' is not iterable
> ```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To use a pytest fixture, you must list it as an argument to your function:

   ```
   def test_http_client(event_loop, http_client):
   ```
2. AsyncHTTPClient is not callable; it has a `fetch` method:

   ```
   resp = event_loop.run_until_complete(http_client.fetch(url))
   ```

What's happening in your code is that you're calling the fixture instead of letting pytest initialize it, and passing `url` as its `tornado_server` argument.

Also consider using `pytest-asyncio` or `pytest-tornado`, which lets you use `await` instead of `run_until_complete` (this is the usual method of using pytest with tornado or asyncio):

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_http_client(http_client):
    url = 'http://httpbin.org/get'
    resp = await http_client.fetch(url)
    assert resp.code == 200
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `assert "200" in resp.code` or `assert "OK" in resp.reason`in your test_http_client() function.

The object that is getting assigned to `resp` is the AsyncHTTPClient, not the response itself. To call the response message, you need something like `resp.code, resp.reason, resp.body, resp.headers`, etc.

Here's a list of things that you can call http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#response-objects